# Why does this loop not break immediately when the user inputs -0.1

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, int, scanf

I was reviewing some exercises I did for my algorithms class when I stumbled onto this piece of code and it didn't work as I thought it would.

So the exercise is the following: write a program that asks for a positive integer then print its double unless the number is negative.

So here is the code:

```
int main(void) {
    int n = 1;

    while (n >= 0) {
        printf("Veuillez introduire un nombre entier positif: ");

        if (!(scanf("%i", &n)) || n < 0) 
            break;

        printf("Le double de %i est de: %i\n", n, (2 * n));
    } 
}
```

Simple enough.

The thing is that the program stops immediately if I try to input a character, a negative number,… as expected but if I input "-0.1" it first prints the double of 0 which is 0 then runs the loop again up to the if statement.

If I just input 0 or even -0 it doesn't do that it keeps running (which it should since 0 isn't a negative number).

Here is the output:

```
Veuillez introduire un nombre entier positif: -0  
Le double de 0 est de: 0  
Veuillez introduire un nombre entier positif: 1  
Le double de 1 est de: 2  
Veuillez introduire un nombre entier positif: -0.1  
Le double de 0 est de: 0  
Veuillez introduire un nombre entier positif:
```

It stops there.

I just can't wrap my head around this. Sorry if this is trivial.

Thank you for your time.

NB: This is my first post, I haven't found the answer here, so if you found it or if you have feedback feel free to post it, it'd be appreciated.

EDIT: swapped screenshot of output with text

Comment: -0 is not less than 0. Since you asked scanf() for an integer, it saw the 0, then the '.', and stopped, because integers don't have '.' in them.

Comment: you are entering a float for an int.

Comment: He entered an int just fine. He also happened to enter some garbage characters ".1" after it.

Comment: Well I think I misspoke. I expect it to stop with -0.1. What I don't understand is that it runs through the loop again up to the if statement. It doesn't do that if the input is incorrect. So, if I understand what you're saying is that scanf didn't return EOF until it was called again?

Comment: @lemonChief Yes, that's correct. See [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48716357/539810).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the format `%i`, `scanf()` reads an integer. If you type `-0.1`, the integer is `-0`. This isn't less than `0`, so the loop continues.

The next time through the loop, it tries to read an integer from `.1`. Since this isn't an integer, the scan fails and `scanf()` returns `0`. This causes `!scanf("%i", &n)` to be true, so `break;` is executed and the loop stops.

Comment: Thank you that makes it pretty clear. Is there any way to avoid that happening if I must use scanf?

Comment: Maybe you should read a whole line with `fgets()`, then use `sscanf()` to parse the number from that.

Comment: You could use `scanf("%i\n", &n)` This requires the integer to be followed by a newline, so it will fail if they type anything that's not only an integer.

Comment: `scanf("%i\n", &n)` actually doesn't work for me here. It does the same. Too bad, that would have been a very elegant solution :/

Comment: So why can't you just put `fgets()` on the line before `if`?

Comment: Or just `int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar();` following each input to empty the input buffer of all extraneous characters.